# Identity Server 4 - auto sign-In is slow

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Below is my code to sign-In the user

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", new AuthenticationProperties()
{
   RedirectUri = Url.Action("Dashboard", "Account", Request.Scheme)
});
```

The above code is working fine, but having a performance issue. It seems always taking 6-8 seconds to complete the authorization, Impact: The user is seeing the blank page for 8 secs. Is there any other better way to improve it?

Below is the only available log 
GET account/login 1.8 seconds, other than this all seems around 40ms.

**Note** : I am using Identity server 4 and Dot net core.

Comment: Can you ensure that after singing in for a second and a third time, it still has such a long delay? (Sign-in while staying in the same instance of the app)

Comment: Hi @Twenty, Yes It seems always taking around the same time. Inmemory cache is already there. But do not know what need to fix.

Comment: Where does most of the time come from?

Comment: Hi @RuardvanElburg,
What are the configurations? Any idea?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the network trace that's generated from one of the browsers this was observed on?